# Cant remove duplicates from jtable.

Tags: java, mysql, hashset, duplicates

I have two different table in mysql and I want to combine them in one table. I combined but there is copies and I cant delete them. I used Hashset firstly and it worked for first table but when i combined second table it disappeared. And now I dont want to write some long calculations because project is too big and its working with database so it will work slowly.

[image]

```
public final class IsdenCixanlar extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public final String[][] array;
public final List<Pojo> list;
public int index = 0;
public String ad = null;

public JTable autoResizeColWidth(JTable table, TableModel model) {
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setModel(model);
    int margin = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        int vColIndex = i;
        DefaultTableColumnModel colModel = (DefaultTableColumnModel) table.getColumnModel();
        TableColumn col = colModel.getColumn(vColIndex);
        int width;
        TableCellRenderer renderer = col.getHeaderRenderer();
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
        }
        Component comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, col.getHeaderValue(), false, false, 0, 0);
        width = comp.getPreferredSize().width;
        for (int r = 0; r < table.getRowCount(); r++) {
            renderer = table.getCellRenderer(r, vColIndex);
            comp = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, table.getValueAt(r, vColIndex), false, false,
                    r, vColIndex);
            width = Math.max(width, comp.getPreferredSize().width);
        }
        width += 2 * margin;
        col.setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
    ((DefaultTableCellRenderer) table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer()).setHorizontalAlignment(
            SwingConstants.LEFT);
    table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
    return table;
}

public IsdenCixanlar() {
    initComponents();
    //setTitle("İşdən çıxanlar");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    list = new ArrayList<>(DBO.salary());
    for (Iterator<Pojo> itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        Pojo element = itr.next();
        if (element.getIsleyir() == 0) {
            itr.remove();
        }
        if ("null".equals(element.getAd())) {
            itr.remove();
        }
        if ("".equals(element.getAd())) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
    array = new String[list.size()][2];
    list.stream().forEach((list1) -> {
        if (ad == null ? list1.getAd() != null : !ad.equals(list1.getAd())) {
            array[index][0] = list1.getAd();
            array[index][1] = DBO.cixarilma_qayitma_Find_Tarix(array[index][0], 0).getTarix();
            index++;
        }
        ad = list1.getAd();
    });
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
            array,
            new String[]{
                "Ad / Soyad / Ata adı", "İşdən çıxarılma tarixi"
            }
    ) {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    table = autoResizeColWidth(table, model);
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    table.setModel(model);
    table = new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    add(pane);
}
```

Comment: Why not use MySQL to remove the duplicates? Show me the data structures and I will be able to help you with that. MySQL will be much faster than Java at this I can assure you.

Comment: I just need all data on other tables. Because of it I need to remove them on this table only

Comment: You can still do this inside SQL which will be a LOT faster than Java.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer.

```
list = new ArrayList<>(DBO.salary());
    for (Iterator<Pojo> itr = list.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        Pojo element = itr.next();
        if (element.getIsleyir() == 0) {
            itr.remove();
        }
        if ("null".equals(element.getAd())) {
            itr.remove();
        }
        if ("".equals(element.getAd())) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    list.stream().forEach((list1) -> {
        hs.add(list1.getAd());
    });
    al.addAll(hs);
    array = new String[list.size()][2];
    al.stream().forEach((list1) -> {
        if (ad == null ? list1 != null : !ad.equals(list1)) {
            array[index][0] = (String) list1;
            array[index][1] = DBO.cixarilma_qayitma_Find_Tarix(array[index][0], 0).getTarix();
            index++;
        }
        ad = (String) list1;
    });
```